# Using PHP to upload a file that's generated by a URL

Tags: php, url, upload

So, I have a little PHP code that uses Kaywa to generate and display a QR code:

```
 echo "<img src='http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=10&d=$qr_url' alt='QR code' />";
```

Easy peasy. But for the sake of having a backup, I'd like to save this image to my server, maybe in "myserver/qrbackups". I know how to make PHP upload a file from a form, but can I do from a retrieved image URL?

Answer (score 2):

See [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=10&d=$qr_url");
$saved = file_put_contents('/path/to/myserver/qrbackups/the-code.png', $data);
```

Keep in mind `/path/to/myserver/qrbackups/the-code.png` should be a unique file name for each individual QR code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to programmatically access URLs.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use curl or file_get_contents to pull the file from the server.

For example:
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php

And after getting the file just display the one you got from your server or remote.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy('http://domain.com/path', '/tmp/file.jpeg');
```

should work for you. And, as others have pointed you, cURL will work too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the GD extension on your server, you can use a library like [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) to eliminate the dependency on Kaywa. Usage requires only one line of code wherever you want to generate a QR code.